# Initializing error variable as error pointer

Tags: go

Trying to handle all error in a single defer function.
But err can't be assigned as a pointer to error? As it gives me Invalid memory address error

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

func main() {
    var err *error

    defer func(err *error) {
        if *err != nil {
            fmt.Println("hi")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("oh")
        }
    }(err)
    *err = errors.New("EMPTY_BODY")
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DxkGobgVWnM)

Comment: Why are you using a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

I never needed to pass pointer

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

func main() {
    var err error

    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("hi")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("oh")
        }
    }()
    err = errors.New("EMPTY_BODY")
}
```

I thought i needed as defer was taking the value of err at that point not at the end of function.

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign the memory to the err where you are just defining now.

Replace **`var err *error`** with **`var err = new(error)`** or **`err := new(error)`** to instantiate and make this code work.